# Jest spyOn hook and sending a parameter

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I used to use `spyOn` this way always successful:

```
jest.spyOn(Hooks, "useGetTableData").mockImplementation({ refetch: jest.fn() });
```

However this time, the specific hook needs an argument. In the component it is being run this way:

```
const type = `typleOfTable`
const { refetch } = useGetTableData(TYPE);
```

How can I use spyOn the same way, however sending to the hook a specific string?

Comment: Yes, you're right. With your current code, you're mocking the entire implementation of `useGetTableData`, so it doesn't really matter what the original function takes in as an argument. You code will always return your mocked implementation, i.e `{ refetch: jest.fn() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `mockImplementation` with `spyOn` you are just mocking the function so I believe you are fine with using mocks.

in this case you can assign `refetch`'s mock `jest.fn()` and then just use it:

```
const refetchMock = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(Hooks, "useGetTableData").mockImplementation({ refetch: refetchMock });
```